# Spring REST: 404 on simple REST Request

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm desperatly trying to get my Rest controller to work. It's a simple Rest controller **that has worked yesterday** but won't after today's build. I haven't changed a single line just rebuilt the project.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ws")
  public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepo;

  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public String hello() {return "Hello";}  .....
```

At:

> http://localhost:8080/ws/hello

Errormessage:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Eclipse is driving me crazy. Everytime I cleanup the build I take the risk that my code won't work anymore.

POM.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>      
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: project deployed properly ? try refreshing project before build.

Comment: Nope. Still 404

Comment: By any chance, have configured 'server.contextPath' in either applicationcontext.xml or yml file? Also if you enable the debug log for the spring package, which should tell you what are all API endpoints are discovered in your code and corresponding fully qualified method name. This will help you to debug further.

Comment: configuring contextPath hasn't changed anything. As said the code has worked yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by transfering the project to a new copy of STS. Can't tell what has damaged eclipse.